# glFog causing transparent png to lose transparency

Tags: c++, opengl

Without glFog, my transparent png displays fine, but with it you can see the rectanglular background and strips of other colours (notice the other dirt material is working as intended, but not using a png or transparency).

[alt text http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/4466/screenshot20100509at528.png](http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/4466/screenshot20100509at528.png)[alt text http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/3131/screenshot20100509at456.png](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/3131/screenshot20100509at456.png)

Here's my code for the fog:

```
GLfloat colour[4]={0.8f,0.8f,1.0f, 1.0f};
glFogi(GL_FOG_MODE, GL_EXP);
glFogfv(GL_FOG_COLOR, colour);
glFogf(GL_FOG_DENSITY, 0.1);
glHint(GL_FOG_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glFogf(GL_FOG_START, 1.0);
glFogf(GL_FOG_END, 5.0);
glEnable(GL_FOG);   
glClearColor(0.8f,0.8f,1.0f,1.0f);
```

And my code for the png:

```
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    GLfloat myAmbient[] = {0.7,0.7,0.7,1.0};
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, myAmbient);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, plantTexture);
    glColor3f(0.5,0.5,0.2);

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(-1,-14,10);
        glScaled(10,10,10);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glNormal3f(0,0,1);
            glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2i(1,0);
            glNormal3f(0,0,1);
            glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2i(1,1);
            glNormal3f(0,0,1);
            glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2i(0,1);
            glNormal3f(0,0,1);
            glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2i(0,0);
        glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

I'm completely lost on this one. Any ideas?

Comment: some questions : what order do you draw things in ? Do you use alpha-test ? what do the colors in the transparent parts of the png look like ? What happens if you use alpha = 0 for the fog color ?

Answer (score 1):

Since your quad is translucent, you should disable writes to the depth buffer with glDepthMask(false) prior to draw it (assuming GL_DEPTH_TEST is enabled).